# How to autoscale volume in realtime with lightweight-charts?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, tradingview-api

I am using lightweight charts in node/react. I have set `autoscale` to *true* to update the data for price and volume as new data comes in live. However, the data is not scaled even though the price data is in the range of 1000-2000, while the volume varies from 1000-80000. So the chart looks like this;(black bars are volume and green is price)
[image]

```
 const firstChart = createChart(chartContainer, {
      layout: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff5",
        textColor: "#00000",
      },
      priceScale: {
        position: "left",
        autoscale: true,
      },
      timeScale: {
        timeVisible: true,
        secondsVisible: true,
      },
    });

    const candlestickSeries = firstChart.addCandlestickSeries({
      upColor: "#4bffb5",
      downColor: "#c72867",
      borderDownColor: "#c72867",
      borderUpColor: "#4bffb5",
      wickDownColor: "#c72867",
      wickUpColor: "#f2e9e9",
    });
    const volumeSeries = firstChart.addHistogramSeries(
      {
        color: "#182233",
        lineWidth: 2,
        priceFormat: {
          type: "volume",
        },

        overlay: true,
      },
      []
    );
```